# Forward type parameters to generic type when implementing generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Say I'm given a function type like so. I can already implement a function of that type, and not need to declare the argument or return types again:

```
type MyFunc = (args: string) => boolean;

// TS knows args is a string and return is boolean 
const myFunc: MyFunc = (args) => true;
```

However, say I'm given a generic function type. I'd like to implement a function that adheres to this type, but forward the generic type parameters to the caller. Is this possible? My attempt gives an error :

```
type ReturnsSomething<A> = (args: A) => A;

// Generic type 'ReturnsSomething' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)
const logAndReturnSomething: ReturnsSomething = (args) => {
  console.log(args);
  return args;
};

logAndReturnSomething<string>('asdf');
```

This also does not work:

```
type ReturnsSomething<A> = (args: A) => A;

// Cannot find name 'A'.ts(2304)
const logAndReturnSomething: ReturnsSomething<A> = (args) => {
  console.log(args);
  return args;
};

logAndReturnSomething<string>('asdf');
```

In more complicated cases, I don't want to redefine the args and return types on all my implementations as that defeats the purpose of a shareable `ReturnsSomething` generic. Is there any way to implement a generic function that forwards it's type arguments to a generic type?

I could create a wrapper function to enforce this type, but that means I need a double function call on every use, I wish there was a cleaner way:

```
type ReturnsSomething<A> = (args: A) => A;

function makeLogAndReturnSomething<A>(): ReturnsSomething<A> {
  return (args) => {
    console.log(args);
    return args;
  };
}

makeLogAndReturnSomething<string>()('asdf');
```

I'm using typescript 4.6 for what it's worth, not sure if 4.7 will address this or if there's some  TS syntax I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
type GenericFn = <A>(args: A) => A;

const logAndReturnSomething: GenericFn = (args) => {
  console.log(args);
  return args;
};

const result = logAndReturnSomething('asdf'); //infers return type as string
```

In essence, we are not creating a generic type, but rather a generic function. It's confusing I know :)

There is a great short [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IFf1GlpLv4) If you want to dig deeper.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgMXlAvFAPAIIB8AFAIZIDmAzgFxSECUuxjA3AFCdoD28NYFAA2vKoXgATAEoRgAVyTwAyrwC2cgBYp4VBnESpM2PBWo0WONgG9OUKHwG9hEAHSiqZ2ky72kcxWxKWi4AXy4efkEofxp5YSE8DwkZAKVVDWBtXVIAcnIaSQAzXJ8gA)

Comment: Thanks, this works well and I'll use this in the future. My problem goes deeper I guess as I'm not in control of the `GenericFn` type, the library I'm using provides something like `type ReturnsSomething<A> = (args: A) => A;` so I can't make it not a generic type. Still, thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much man, I was almost givin up